# How to echo php Session when using objects

Tags: php, session, object

I can't figure this out and have tried it several ways.

I have a multi-page form where form_1.php, upon submit, sends info to the DB and redirects to form_2.php.

I start a session on form_1.php with:

```
<?PHP
if ($_POST)
{
    session_start();

    foreach ($_POST as $field => $value)
    {
        $_SESSION['formdata'][$field] = $value; 
    }
}
.....code that sends info to db and then redirects page to form_2.php
?>
```

When I get to form_2.php I have:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    // Used for later to determine result
    $success = $error = false;

    // Object syntax looks better and is easier to use than arrays to me
    $post = new stdClass;

    // Usually there would be much more validation and filtering, but this
    // will work for now.
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
        $post->$key = trim(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));

....more code that loads dompdf and sends a pdf to email
?>
```

If I use something like :

```
<?php echo $post->Name; ?>
<?php echo $post->Address; ?>
<?php echo $post->City; ?>
<?php echo $post->State; ?>
```

Where I want the data displayed I get nothing.

Is there a way to write this that's equivalent to :

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['Name'] ?>
```

Is it because I am using objects?

If I wipe everything from form_2.php and just print the session using:

```
<?php 
 session_start(); 
 Print_r ($_SESSION);
 ?>
```

I see the data I want like :

```
Array ( [sfm_from_iframe] => 0 [formdata] => Array ( [sfm_form_submitted] => yes [Employer_Zip] => 33333 [Injury_type] => Array ( [0] => Head [1] => Left Shoulder [2] => Chest ) [FirstName] => test [LastName] => tester [Address] => 1212 myaddy [City] => city1 [State] => Maine [Zip] => 55555 [Country] => AntiguaAndBarbuda [Phone] => 555-555-5555 [Email] => me@mydomain.com [Employer_Name] => my employer [Employer_Address] => 1212 empaddy [Employer_City] => city2 [Employer_State] => Georgia [DBA_Carrier] => mycarrier [Employer_Phone] => 333-333-3333 [Accident_Date] => 10-03-2011 [Message] => asefsafsadf sadf asdfsdafsadf [yes_no] => yes [SocialSecurity] => 333-33-3333 [Submit_x] => 57 [Submit_y] => 13 ) )
```

Additional notes that may be helpful...

When I just use POST to form_2.php and use

```
<?php echo $post->Name; ?> 
<?php echo $post->Address; ?> 
<?php echo $post->City; ?>
```

everything is shown and works fine but only using POST directly to that page. Not using the redirect because I think I am screwing up something with writing how to echo a SESSION object.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't quite understand what your session trouble is. Can we get the source code for form_2.php?

Answer (score 0):

Are you redirecting like this:

form1 -submit-> file that inserts in DB -redirect-> form2

If that's the case then you should know that POST data isn't being forwarded to the third page. It's hard to give a good answer without more information but maybe you should include your DB insertion script at the top of form2 and forward form1 directly to form2 or you should save your POST data to your session to be then fetched at the top of form2.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I am using simfatic forms (software) to send all the info to the DB ...It just creates a redirect after submitted so I am not sure if I am correct or not when saying there is no POST to form_2.php. Just a redirect. The code from simfatic just defines a redirect like this :  $tupage =  new FM_ThankYouPage();
$tupage->SetRedirURL("http://myurl.com/pdf_email/form_2.php");
$formmailobj->addModule($tupage);

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up code provided by your OOP Framework (probably some kind of CMS) and you try to use $post when you data is not there.

$_SESSION is used to keep data between page changes. You can, in your form2.php use the following code to merge all together:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val){
        $post->$key = trim(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));
}
foreach($_SESSION['formdata'] as $key => $val){
        $post->$key = trim(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));
}
```

Then, when you check your $post object, you should now have your data in there.

Good luck

Comment: I believe your right that something is being mixed ...
This was added as a hack to the simfatic form :
if ($_POST)
{
 session_start();
 
 foreach ($_POST as $field => $value)
 {
  $_SESSION['formdata'][$field] = $value; 
 }
}

this was being used on form_2 because on form 2 I using dompdf and this made easier

// Object syntax looks better and is easier to use than arrays to me
 $post = new stdClass;
 
 // Usually there would be much more validation and filtering, but this
 // will work for now.
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
  $post->$key = trim(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));